# Why HttpClient uses an incorrect requestUri in post request?

Tags: c#, httprequest, httpclient

When I use `HttpClient` class to send a POST request to an API URL, it modifies the URL that I've passed to it. For example, when I use the main API URL the `RequestUri` is incorrect and I receive the not found response. This problem happens when I use `api` word in the URL !!

Concept:

```
The Incorrect, modified URL:

Url: https://sandbox-api.alopeyk.com/api/v2/order 
Request Url: https://sandbox-api.alopeyk.com
```

---

```
The Correct, and expected URL (This is the one I specify)

Url: https://google.com/api/v2/order
Request Url: https://google.com/api/v2/order
```

Code:

```
public async Task<CreateOrderResponse> CreateOrderAsync(CreateOrderRequest request)
{
     var endPoint = EndPointFactory<CreateOrderResponse>.Build(HttpMethod.Post);

    var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);

    var url = new Uri("https://sandbox-api.alopeyk.com");

    var encodedFrom = new StringContent(jsonString);

    var httpClient = endPoint.GetHttpClient(url);

    var httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync("api/v2/orders", encodedFrom).ConfigureAwait(false);

    // when use api it's https://sandbox-api.alopeyk.com it should be https://sandbox-api.alopeyk.com/api/v2/orders
    // when use other host name for example it's correct
    var requesturl = httpResponse.RequestMessage.RequestUri;

    return await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<CreateOrderResponse>().ConfigureAwait(false);
}

 // in the EndPoint class
 public HttpClient GetHttpClient(Uri url)
 {
     return new Http.HttpClientFactory().GetOrCreate(Url, Headers);
 }
```

If you want to see `HttpClientFactory` it's [here](https://gist.github.com/devSoheilAlizadeh/aaaa12eb425c21b84dc2b31c795363cc).

The `HttpClient` have a problem with my main hostname that it's `https://sandbox-api.alopeyk.com`

Comment: problem solved ?

Comment: @danvasiloiu yes.

Comment: and solution was ?

Comment: @danvasiloiu The API server was redirected me to another page :D

Answer (score 3):

Your Uri must end with a slash like this:

```
  var url = new Uri("https://sandbox-api.alopeyk.com/");
```

That's a rather silly restriction of HttpClient.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
   client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://sandbox-api.alopeyk.com");
   HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("api/v2/orders", new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "text/json")).Result;  
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    // Parse the response body. Blocking!
                   var  responseData = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;                    

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post,"https://sandbox-api.alopeyk.com/api/v2/orders"))
                {
                    request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", /*token herer*/);
                    var data = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
request.Content = data;
                    response = await client.SendAsync(request);
                }
            }
```